# Google UiApp reset UI Application

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script I am making that is essentially a form that submits an email.  There is a submit and a reset button.  My goal I am hoping to accomplish is the the Reset button either reloads the Google Site, or reloads the App Script.
Is there a function in Google Apps Scripts that I can use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

By putting everything in a panel (horizontal, vertical, scroll, etc), you can do the following in your server handler for your form submit

```
app = UiApp.getActiveApplication().remove(0);
/*add whatever you want here using app */
return app;
```

This removes the first item in the app (the panel) and lets you add whatever.
You could also use a client handler with an initially invisible item. On submit, hide the form and show a message until the server handler returns.

Unfortunately, there is no way to refresh the page.

**Edit:** *Adding what I wrote in the comment so it's readable:*

The way I usually set mine up, doGet and the handler both call another function with arguments for the new/current app and whatever values my listboxes have. For example,

```
function doGet(e){
    return actuallyCreateGadget(UiApp.createApplication(), "default value for listbox");
}
function actuallyCreateGadget(app, selectedValue){
    //do stuff here and finish by returning app
}
function serverHandlerFunction(e){
    return actuallyCreateGadget(UiApp.getActiveApplication().remove(0), e.parameter.lbFirst);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, is there any way to upon removing, call the doGet function?

`function resetForm(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication().remove(0);
  return app;
}
function doGet(e){
//THIS IS WHERE THE FORM IS BUILT
}`

Comment: The way I usually set mine up, doGet and the handler both call another function with arguments for the new/current app and whatever values my listboxes have. I put an example in my answer.

Comment: Brilliant.  That is a great solution.  After reading your first comment I copied the code from doGet into function resetForm, and it worked, but added 200 lines of unnecessary script.  I shall try it this way, and I'll let you know how it goes.  Thanks again!

Comment: I forgot to include .remove(0) in the second example in the server handler. This way, the panel is removed before being created and added again.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that once it made a second instance of the application under the first one.  So, it worked!  I just have to have some people test it, and find a way to add another "Loading" message on Reset Button click because it takes like 5 seconds to rebuild.  The form I am working on builds dynamic forms from txt documents in google apps so that each department can submit a txt doc and their form will be populated.  This was pretty much the last thing that it needed, so I appreciate it very much!